# beep на linux после перезагрузки перестает звучать

Tags: linux, аудио, драйвер

Чтобы `beep` зазвучал загружаю дрова `sudo modprobe pcspkr`, после этого работает в терминале. Но после перезагрузки звук пропадает и приходится дрова загружать заново. Как полечить или может другой способ или другие дрова какие подскажите?

Comment: Прописать модуль в автозагрузку, подробности читайте в справке вашего дистрибутива

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для автоматического подключения модулей в программу *linux* при её загрузке можно воспользоваться [файлом в каталоге `/etc/modules-load.d/`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#.D0.90.D0.B2.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D1.83.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.B4.D1.83.D0.BB.D1.8F.D0.BC.D0.B8).

создайте в этом каталоге файл с произвольным именем с суффиксом `.conf` и впишите в него имена требующихся модулей (по одному на строку).

например:

```
$ echo pcspkr | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/load-speaker-module.conf
```

Comment: С п а с и б о !

Answer (score 0):

В Centos 6 открыть конфигурационный файл /etc/modprobe.d/beep.conf, который имеет следующее содержимое:

```
# Uncomment the following line to have the pcspkr driver loaded
# automatically on boot
# alias platform:pcspkr pcspkr
```

уберем комментарий с последней строки (как просят нас по английски) для автоматической подгрузки модуля pcspkr

```
# Uncomment the following line to have the pcspkr driver loaded
# automatically on boot

  alias platform:pcspkr pcspkr
```

Теперь, после перезагрузки компьютера, модуль pcspkr будет подгружаться автоматически